# What is the maximum allowed file name length in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, save

I am trying to save a picture in Windows Phone Device Library with SavePicture method.
I have a picture "name"

computer-background-hd-wallpaper-3Dsuperb_lake_and_mountain_1920x1080_wallpaper_1976_1__9_9_2015_8_23_44____1__10_9_2015_6_37_07____8__15_9_2015_11_26_18____1__22_9_2015_4_54_27____11_3_2015_4_47_11_PM_04_11_2015_10_3.jpg

and I get an exception 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll
So the question is:

What is the maximum allowed file name length in Windows Phone ?

Comment: It is 260 characters but not very sure!

Comment: Assuming that this limit is calculated as filepath + filename length ? Because my example  filename length is 221 and I don't know the filepath.

Comment: Yes it takes the file path also, https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/12/01/long-filenames-in-windows-8.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx